# PHP: question about passing parameters in URL's

Tags: php, url, parameter-passing

i have this two lines:

```
  var_dump($parametros_post_signin);

  $this->redirect('prueba/aux?email='.$parametros_post_signin['signin']);
```

the first one prints this:

```
array
  'signin' => 
    array
      'email_address' => string '' (length=0)
      'password' => string '' (length=0)
```

the second one takes to another action where i have this code:

```
var_dump($request->getParameter('email'));
```

that prints this:

*string 'password' (length=8)*

I expected it to print something like this:

string '' (length=0)

What should i do to the get value of the 'email_address' field ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$parametros_post_signin['signin']
```

with

```
$parametros_post_signin['signin']['email_address']
```

in the `2nd` line.

`$parametros_post_signin` is a `2D` array, to get to the `email address` you'll have to specify two dimensions.